# How do I copy values from one dictionary to a second dictionary with new keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am trying to make weapons in my game exclusive to certain classes. I have an item database in form:

```
itemsList = {
1: {"name": "Padded Armor",  "armor": 1,  "value": 5, "class": "light"},
2: {"name": "Leather Armor",  "armor": 2,  "value": 10, "class": "light"},
3: {"name": "Studded Leather Armor",  "armor": 3,  "value": 25, "class": "light"},
...
19: {"name": "Dagger", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4)), "value": 2, "Type": "Dagger"},
20: {"name": "Dagger + 1", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4) + 1), "value": 200, "Type": "Dagger"},
21: {"name": "Dagger + 2", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4) + 2), "value": 750, "Type": "Dagger"},
22: {"name": "Dagger + 3", "damage" : int(random.randrange(1, 4) + 3), "value": 2000, "Type": "Dagger"}
}
```

I am going to import, if a class can equip a certain weapon, to a new dictionary,

```
character.canEquipWeapon = {}
```

I would like to assign the name, damage, value, and type to a new set of keys in the dictionary, only, I would like to add only certain subsets (daggers, maces, swords) to certain classes.

I have tried

```
character.canEquipWeapon.update(itemsList[5])
```

and that just overwrites the dictionary with each new value. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You're not actually providing the *"new keys"* - try `character.canEquipWeapon.update({'whatever': itemsList[5]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dict with usable items by class, so that for a given class, you have the list of the IDs it can equip as such :

```
classItem = {
          'rogue'   : [1,2,3,12,13,14,15], 
          'mage'    : [13,15,16,18], 
          'soldier' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
         }
```

Then to get the list of items usable by the rogue for instance :

```
rogueItems = [v for k,v in itemsList.items() if k in classItem['rogue']]
```

Note that with python2 you'd have to use `itemsList.iteritems()` instead of `itemsList.items()`

Comment: I like this answer, but I tested the rogueItems and it gave me an invalid syntax error. I even imported iteritems. Is there any way to call a specific item in rogueItems as well?

Comment: what's your version of python?

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.6, Cloud9 IDE

Comment: so you need to use iteritems : `rogueItems = [v if k in classItem['rogue'] for k,v in itemsList.iteritems()]`

Comment: It still says invalid syntax. Sorry if I'm stupidly missing something. I did import iteritems as well.

Comment: you don't import `iteritems`. Please show me the full error message

Comment: The full error message is
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from playerInfo import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/playerInfo.py", line 442
    rogueWeapons = [v if k in classItem['rogue'] for k,v in itemsList.iteritems()]

Comment: If you'd like to keep the ID, you could use a dict almost the same way :
rogueItems = {k:v for k,v in itemsList.iteritems() if k in classItem['rogue']}

Comment: Ooh, that's even better, thank you for your help. This way I should be able to access items during the initial equipment during character creation.

Comment: You're welcome, even though I disagree with classes that can't equip weapons idea! I could equip a war bow right now, and even use it, even though I'd be bad at it. Why don't you use weapon profficiency the D&D way? :-p

Comment: Good idea! I was going the Final Fantasy route, but perhaps I'll use the "rogueItems" list as a record of proficiencies, and then if proficient add +1 to attack rolls and +2 to damage!

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel about making `itemsList` an array instead of a dict? Seems like you're using it as an array anyhow. That way, you could do something like

```
itemsList2 = [weapon for weapon in itemsList if weapon.type == "dagger"]
```

or if the weapon types are stored in, say, `character.weaponTypes`

```
itemsList2 = [weapon for weapon in itemsList if weapon.type in character.weaponTypes]
```

Comment: What would a line of it as an array look like?

Comment: `itemsList = [{"name":"dagger", ...., "class":"light"}, {"name":"dagger +1" ...}, ...]`

Comment: The only issue I have with that style is that the items don't have an associated ID number.

Comment: @Dragoonknight then maybe my answer would be better for you since it keeps the ID.